# How to get a good overview of team member utilization across multiple projects in TFS 2013

Tags: team-management, reporting, tfs

I would like to be able to see a weekly summary of scheduled hours of work across all TFS Team Projects in TFS 2013 for myself and other team member. This would, for example, let me look a few weeks out and see that in two weeks I can schedule an iteration for myself and a co-worker without fear of overloading either one of us. I am interested in data and charts similar to the following:

[image: Example data]

[image: Example pivot chart]

For the most part each team member manages their own workload, and is assigned to a couple active projects at any given time with one or more other team members. Member/project relationships look like this:

```
Members A, B assigned to Project A
Members A, C assigned to Project B
Members B, C assigned to Project C
Member C assigned to Project D
...
```

Having recently started using TFS 2013 and the Visual Studio Scrum 2013 process template, I have not been able to figure out how to tease this information out. Each project our group writes or supports has its own TFS Team Project within a single collection.

Related:

- [How to get a good overview of projects using TFS 2012](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/how-to-get-a-good-overview-of-projects-using-tfs-2012)
- [How can I schedule resources across multiple projects?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/how-can-i-schedule-resources-across-multiple-projects)

Comment: There is a great answer below, but I'd like to add that you should probably be only using a single Team Project, and controlling different physical projects with area paths. That will significantly reduce your reporting barriers and make you life much easier. Check out this resource: http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx

Comment: This too: http://nakedalm.com/working-within-a-single-team-project-with-team-foundation-server-2012/. At MS they run thousands of users on dozens of physical projects from the same Team Project (its a horrible name)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewClear I've read both articles and do not see how they help address my request, nor have the answers thus far. Any suggestions on summarizing future workloads by week and team member would be appreciated.

Comment: When you're in a single team project you get that rollup for free in iteration planning.

Comment: More info on this here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/work-in-sprints-vs.aspx (there are a couple of screenshots in the Q&A section which I believe are what you're looking for)

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how to tease the information out of TFS, however if you are willing to use another tool that integrates into TFS, I would suggest [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMStack#Manageperformance). It offers time tracking as a feature and generates time reports based on what you need. The reports are generated for each team member individually, including all of the projects they are working on.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the screenshot you present is of tracked time, and not future, estimated time. Is Eylean capable of presenting that kind of information? From the site you linked to: "Tracked time is summed up and shown in time reports."

Answer (score 2):

TFS 2013 has very comprehensive web portal which was not available in previous versions. 
In order to see the distribution of developers among different projects,  first you have to write the new query. In you new query delete the 'Team Project' clause which comes by default.

Your new query should look  like this
[image]

Than click run.

The system will bring all the team projects and workers. If you want to narrow down your search, you have select 'Assigned to' and select Member A, Member B and Member C, in your case.
This look like this

[image]

As you can see, all the information is dispalyed so that you can see if Member A is assigned to multiple projects, and how much time is remaining for the work to be completed. 
You are free to edit the columns to display the info which is relevant for you.

Hope this helps!

EDIT

You may get any sort of data and reports out of TFS 2013. Go to 'My query', go to 'charts' and there you will see 'New chart' button. Here you can specify rows and columns to obtain report, like this
[image]

These charts indicates exactly what you need, besides the calculations you have done.
If you need further analysis, you can use SQL reporting services if it is configured for TFS 2013 . In web portal, there is 'View reports' link, which directs you to the report builder.

The spreadsheet you posted cannot be generated exactly in this way. Unfortunately, tfs displays the tasks for the entire team project, and not for iteration starting on a fixed start date and stopping on a fixed finish date.

Comment: Thank you. I've played around with rolling up multiple projects by removing the project filter from queries like you describe here. That is a step in the right direction but doesn't go far enough. I've added example data and a chart to my question. Do you have any suggestions for getting that sort of data and chart out of TFS?

Comment: @JeremyCook see the edits

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation of TFS's capabilities. Unfortunately the charts do not solve my problem, as you've noted. It is sounding like I need to looking into using SSRS. If you care to post another answer that goes into using SSRS to solve this problem that would be appreciated.

Comment: @JeremyCook I will definitely dig deeper into it, If I find the solution will post my answer by Friday! Your question is really interesting.Additionally, if you find the solution, let me know please

Comment: I will post a solution here if I come up with one. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I belive TFS 2013 comes with an Agile Portfolio Management tool.

It allows you to define a management team and then members of that team can see the backlog and I belive capacity of team members across multiple projects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306083.aspx

I should caveat this by saying we have not moved to TFS 2013 yet so I don't know how it works in practice.